# What value does (Enum) -1 represent in C? How to write it in Swift?

Tags: c, swift, enums

I need to translate C code to Swift, I'm encountering this variable assignment many times but have no clue at what value it represents.

Having this enum in C:

```
typedef XX_ENUM_BEGIN(XXPosition) {
  XXTop,
  XXBottom,
} XX_ENUM_END(XXPosition);
```

Is being assigned to a variable like this:

```
.parentPosition = (XXPosition) -1
```

Is it first enum value, last or nil...?

Comment: Some illegal value. Most likely the enum with ordinal of 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: What are `XX_ENUM_BEGIN` and `XX_ENUM_END`?

Comment: Looks like somebody forgot to explicitly introduce a `XXNeitherOrInvalid,` and tries quite daringly to shoehorn-workaround that - taking any and all risk.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Would this, in your opinion, qualify as a case of 0xFing things up?

Comment: @user4581301 I had to guess and google it up :p Yeah, it is 0xFing things up, but easily fixable, I guess

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, you are right. My mistake.  The code perhaps should explicitly list the -1 as an enumerator (which would force the underlying type to be signed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, enums are ints. The `XX_ENUM_BEGIN` and `XX_ENUM_END` macros are helping set that up so that `XXTop` is 0 and `XXBottom` is 1.

Since C enums are ints, they can actually hold any int value (for whatever size int they're implemented with), not just legal enum values. In this case the code is assigning a value that does not map to anything (-1). C allows that because the `(XXPosition)` says "trust me, I know what I'm doing."

To convert this to Swift, you'll need to make a choice. Either you need to add a new enum case for "none" and use that, or you'll need to make `parentPosition` optional so that it can be `nil`. If this code is just setting `parentPosition` to -1 as a default value (immediately updating it later to something correct), you could also just set it to a default value (like `top`) from the start.

Comment: Excellent answer, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Those macros have nothing to do with what the values of the enumerators are. The first enumerator is always `0` if not explicitly assigned another value. Also the cast is unnecessary, it might be more of a case of the coder reminding the reader that they did it on purpose.